HTML5 <video> background not transparent on iOS
I need to use a HTML5 video tag to display a webm file which plays in a loop. I do not want to show any video background or controls. Currently, it looks like this:
.my_video {
    display: block;  
    border: none;  
    outline: none;  
    pointer-events: none;  
    background-color: transparent !important;  

    &::-webkit-media-controls,  
    &::-webkit-media-controls-panel,  
    &::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,  
    &::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {  
        display: none !important;  
        -webkit-appearance: none !important;  
    }  
}

<video className={styles.my_video} autoPlay loop muted playsInline>
    <source src="/mywebmfile.webm" type="video/webm"/>
</video>

It works on all systems and browsers, but on all browsers iOS mobile devices. There, the video has a black background although the background should be transparent. What do I need to change?

Change the video's codec.  Re-encode from Google's Webm into Apple's own preferred codec H265 (aka HEVC) . You can try some online converters if you don't already have a video editor that can do it. See also Answers to this Question

@VC.One If I do that and change the type to type="video/mp4; codecs=hvc1" or codecs=hev1, it completely disappears from my website. As far as I know, Chrome should be able to display it. Or do I need to provide multiple sources, including a webm file?

Sorry it's late... If still not solved then consider using JS to detect if the browser is Safari or Chrome then set the .src URL to either a MOV or WebM file as needed.
